# Define source ip address using Apache HttpClient

Tags: java, http, httpclient

I'm working on a project that have the following need:

- use source ip address A to access http service S on Remote Server XX.YY.ZZ.WW
- use source ip address B to access http service T on Remote Server XX.YY.ZZ.WW(same as above)

XX.YY.ZZ.WW is a host I have no control of.

My server is configured with both IP A and IP B on the same Ethernet Interface. My project uses Apache HttpClient. It can be changed to something else if necessary.

Based on my TCP/IP knowledge, this is very easy. As long as I own the IP, I should be able to change the source IP address to whatever I want. But after all, I'm not manipulating IP packet directly. And I have no idea how this can be done with HttpClient.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You just need to tell HttpClient which network interface to use. You can do this with a connection property:

```
ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS='ADDRESS A';
```

check out section 2.4 of the [docs](http://hc.apache.org/httpcomponents-client-ga/tutorial/html/connmgmt.html) for a full description.

Comment: The doc says "to be used by all default route planner". How can I use different route planner for different instances of httpclient?  Thank you!

Comment: You'd need to have 2 different HttpClient instances, each configured with your preferred local address.

Comment: Actually, I found the answer myself in documentation. I didn't know it should actually be configured on HttpParams. I thought it would be on something more complicated. Thank you!

Comment: This seems to be STATIC. well what If I have 2 threads for each of connections explained as above? this could cause problem, right ?

Answer (score 6):

```
final DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
HttpParams params = httpClient.getParams();
params.setParameter(ConnRoutePNames.LOCAL_ADDRESS, InetAddress.getByName(IP_ADDRESS));
```