# Can I Change "remote_addr" in my request

Tags: java

If I want to send a request with `HttpsURLConnection`.
Can I change "`remote_addr`" in the header? (if I don't want to get `response`,just want to send the `request` to server)

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can:

```
    URL myURL = new URL("theURLToRequestTo");
    HttpURLConnection myURLConnection = (HttpURLConnection)myURL.openConnection();
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("REMOTE_ADDR", myIPAddress); // Here you can put the IP you want
    myURLConnection.setRequestMethod("GET"); // Or POST as needed
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-TYPE", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-LENGTH", "" + Integer.toString(postData.getBytes().length));
    myURLConnection.setRequestProperty("CONTENT-LANGUAGE", "en-US");
    myURLConnection.setUseCaches(false);
    myURLConnection.setDoInput(true);
    myURLConnection.setDoOutput(true);
```

Update

---

Look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19526039/1358722) solution.

Comment: But the server got my real ip in "REMOTE_ADDR" ,  Not the ip I put in header.